# Как работает bulkDelete? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord-api

Я попытался с помощью `bulkDelete`, чтобы сделать мой бот удалить его сообщение, но я получаю эту ошибку:

```js
TypeError: The messages must be an Array, Collection, or number.
    at TextChannel.bulkDelete (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:478:11)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\cmds\clear.js:14:21)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\index.js:37:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

А вот мой код:

```js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    var args1 = message.content.split(' ')
    var purge = args1[1]
    if(!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.reply('У вас нет прав!')
    if(!purge || isNaN(purge)) {
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription('Укажите число!')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter('Yukimura', client.user.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
    message.channel.bulkDelete(purge).then(m => {
        var embed1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(`Было удалено ${purge} сообщений!`)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter('Yukimura', client.user.avatarURL)
        message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.delete(10000))
    })
}
exports.help = {
    name: 'clear'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Discord.BulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) принимает в качестве первого аргумента коллекцию или массив сообщений для удаления. Вам стоит получить всю эту коллекцию в канале.

```
msg.channel.fetchMessages({limit: messagecount}) // messagecount есть аргумент сообщений которые удаляются
    .then(messages => {
      msg.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
```